# IEEE template: figure creating space in second column?

Tags: spacing, floats, ieeetran

I am having this problem: 
[image: this figure is creating space next to it for no reason?]

I'm not sure what the issue is.  The TeX I'm using for that figure:

```
\begin{figure}[b]
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\columnwidth]{figures/lowflowstitled.png}
\caption{Various techniques can be used to calculate the ``difference'' between two images (in our case, the last frame of one clip and the first frame of the following clip).  We implemented SSD (focus on colors), HOG (focus on edges), and SIFT (focus on semantics).}
\label{fig:flows}
\end{figure}
```

And for some reason this is not a problem with any other figures.  Below is a working example (maybe not minimal), image I'm using is this: [image: image that is being terrible]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.jpg,.png}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{stfloats}


% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

% Load basic packages
\usepackage{balance}  % to better equalize the last page
\usepackage{graphics} % for EPS, load graphicx instead
\usepackage{times}    % comment if you want LaTeX's default font
\usepackage{url}      % llt: nicely formatted URLs
%\usepackage{flushend} % bjoern: attempt to balance last page
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

% llt: Define a global style for URLs, rather that the default one
\makeatletter
\def\url@leostyle{%
  \@ifundefined{selectfont}{\def\UrlFont{\sf}}{\def\UrlFont{\small\bf\ttfamily}}}
\makeatother
\urlstyle{leo}

\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
pdftitle={SIGCHI Conference Proceedings Format},
pdfauthor={LaTeX},
pdfkeywords={SIGCHI, proceedings, archival format},
bookmarksnumbered,
pdfstartview={FitH},
colorlinks,
citecolor=black,
filecolor=black,
linkcolor=black,
urlcolor=black,
breaklinks=true,
}

\begin{document}

\include{inputmacros}
%
% paper title
% Titles are generally capitalized except for words such as a, an, and, as,
% at, but, by, for, in, nor, of, on, or, the, to and up, which are usually
% not capitalized unless they are the first or last word of the title.
% Linebreaks \\ can be used within to get better formatting as desired.
% Do not put math or special symbols in the title.
\title{BrainReader: Effective Visualization\\of fMRI-based Movie Reconstruction}
%
%
% author names and IEEE memberships
% note positions of commas and nonbreaking spaces ( ~ ) LaTeX will not break
% a structure at a ~ so this keeps an author's name from being broken across
% two lines.
% use \thanks{} to gain access to the first footnote area
% a separate \thanks must be used for each paragraph as LaTeX2e's \thanks
% was not built to handle multiple paragraphs
%

\author{Natalia Bilenko, Valkyrie Savage% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{Natalia and Valkyrie are joint first-authors on this work.  They can be reached via email at \emph{nbilenko@berkeley.edu} and \emph{valkyrie@eecs.berkeley.edu}.}% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{Manuscript submitted December 18th, 2014.}}



% The paper headers
\markboth{Computational Photography Final Project, CS 294-84, December 2014}%
{Bilenko and Savage: BrainReader}



% If you want to put a publisher's ID mark on the page you can do it like
% this:
%\IEEEpubid{0000--0000/00\$00.00~\copyright~2014 IEEE}
% Remember, if you use this you must call \IEEEpubidadjcol in the second
% column for its text to clear the IEEEpubid mark.



% use for special paper notices
%\IEEEspecialpapernotice{(Invited Paper)}




% make the title area
\maketitle

% As a general rule, do not put math, special symbols or citations
% in the abstract or keywords.
\begin{abstract}
Previous work in decoding visual experiences based on fMRI activity has been successful in reconstructing images and movies that participants viewed inside an MRI scanner. Reconstruction is done by fitting a forward model that predicts fMRI activity across the brain in response to a set of movies. The model represents brain activity as a linearized function of visual information features that capture the structure of the movies (spatiotemporal Gabor wavelet filters). The forward model is then inverted and used to decode what the subject saw based on their brain responses to a testing set of movies. Decoding is performed by fitting a maximum a posteriori function to a large library of previously unseen movie clips. The top 100 decoded movie clips are then averaged or stitched together to produce a visualization of the decoding. Though the decoding is quite precise when measured quantitatively, these visualizations do not fully reflect its accuracy. We make the visualization more coherent by combining the decoded clips in several improved ways. First, we demonstrate the change in quality gained using weighted averaging.  Then, we use HOG features to select a subset clips similar to the ground truth clip and SIFT flow to find an optimal path in time. Third, we use appearance morphing to visually align the path-arranged clips. Finally, we share the decoded movies resulting from the same stimuli across different participants in the experiment.
\end{abstract}

% Note that keywords are not normally used for peerreview papers.
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
fMRI, decoding, visualization, computational videography.
\end{IEEEkeywords}


\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

Hello i has cheeseburger.

\begin{figure}[b]
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\columnwidth]{figures/lowflowstitled.png}
\caption{Various techniques can be used to calculate the ``difference'' between two images (in our case, the last frame of one clip and the first frame of the following clip).  We implemented SSD (focus on colors), HOG (focus on edges), and SIFT (focus on semantics).}
\label{fig:flows}
\end{figure}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam nisl erat, facilisis quis turpis sit amet, molestie fringilla felis. Proin consectetur rhoncus tortor, at fermentum tortor mattis id. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris fermentum tincidunt arcu, non suscipit tortor egestas eu. Suspendisse vel dignissim metus, ac interdum tellus. Aliquam a libero massa. Maecenas lacinia tortor in ipsum sollicitudin mattis. Vestibulum suscipit vehicula ex eu aliquam. Nam semper diam sit amet ipsum consequat, ut euismod nibh viverra. Maecenas at neque at orci dignissim faucibus. Morbi tincidunt arcu ut tellus faucibus, ac imperdiet ante fringilla. Vivamus at justo blandit, ornare odio hendrerit, fringilla nunc. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Fusce faucibus libero non mattis vehicula. Curabitur lectus magna, commodo nec pulvinar nec, tempor et urna. Sed sodales nisi lectus, vitae fermentum ex mattis eget.

Aliquam turpis sapien, semper id aliquam in, pellentesque vel nulla. Vestibulum eget tristique enim. Aliquam sollicitudin, mi nec sollicitudin tincidunt, mauris lectus sollicitudin quam, eu venenatis mi ante eu urna. Mauris congue ultricies magna eu facilisis. Suspendisse varius ex aliquam egestas gravida. Nunc eget nunc convallis, tristique elit sed, suscipit tortor. Cras interdum eu massa at venenatis. Praesent sit amet ipsum vel enim tristique tincidunt ac a nisl.

Morbi feugiat nibh nibh, at accumsan dolor semper nec. Curabitur faucibus laoreet tincidunt. Aenean luctus, tellus a sagittis malesuada, arcu risus aliquam nisi, vitae placerat neque nisl nec nibh. Sed tincidunt molestie felis, quis interdum metus consequat sit amet. Fusce sem urna, porta in malesuada in, facilisis eget sapien. Suspendisse lacinia elementum lacinia. Aenean ut dolor lobortis, imperdiet quam consectetur, auctor felis. Cras eu suscipit nibh. Ut nec cursus ex. Curabitur bibendum lectus ac leo tincidunt, sed vulputate magna finibus. Cras hendrerit nunc non velit tristique, vitae ultrices mauris consequat. Praesent eget pretium nisi. Aenean vitae metus at metus aliquet volutpat non sit amet odio. Phasellus sapien enim, aliquet vitae augue sit amet, placerat fermentum sapien. Etiam sed tincidunt ligula. Sed finibus orci a purus vulputate euismod.

Etiam varius, augue vel varius laoreet, orci mauris tristique mi, vel ullamcorper leo felis vel ligula. Duis porttitor, mi quis mollis porttitor, sem metus molestie libero, a egestas dolor arcu in dolor. Pellentesque sed tempus lorem, sit amet commodo felis. Nulla a volutpat tellus, nec elementum dolor. Fusce id justo non eros feugiat molestie eu eget urna. Aenean at elementum neque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Mauris finibus, lacus et euismod dapibus, enim nunc aliquet diam, eget lacinia lacus mauris eget ante. Donec finibus enim feugiat felis congue suscipit. Nunc facilisis tellus at nibh efficitur eleifend.

Donec est turpis, feugiat posuere nisl sed, ultrices rutrum lorem. Mauris interdum a odio sit amet hendrerit. Etiam faucibus ornare ante at volutpat. Fusce tempor est non accumsan sodales. Quisque non nulla dui. Sed ut ex ut ante ornare elementum. Donec volutpat posuere ullamcorper. Fusce id lectus est. Mauris sed eros sed sem finibus suscipit. Nullam vitae fermentum eros, eget ultricies ex. Nunc ex dui, egestas non viverra vitae, rhoncus vel nisi. Nulla facilisi. Nullam magna dui, ultrices eu turpis a, auctor mattis arcu. Curabitur accumsan ligula quis ipsum placerat dictum. Mauris consectetur quam et suscipit vehicula. Praesent sit amet tempus metus.

Nunc rutrum tempus aliquet. Nullam ultrices vehicula urna, sed mollis ante finibus ac. Suspendisse a congue felis. Donec in augue vehicula, aliquam diam sollicitudin, porttitor est. Integer quam sem, rhoncus ac euismod vitae, fermentum vitae dolor. Nunc aliquam iaculis dui, et cursus quam. Nunc pulvinar vitae nulla non aliquam. Donec ullamcorper dolor non urna tempor, varius consequat nisi commodo. Morbi sem nisl, commodo eu sem id, sagittis egestas mi. Nullam justo ipsum, gravida nec rhoncus vitae, convallis et urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam iaculis, enim a dapibus suscipit, mi ex vulputate purus, eu dictum sapien dolor eget sapien. Donec maximus dolor nibh, a sodales velit tristique ut.

Pellentesque ornare enim consequat, molestie nisi in, vestibulum nulla. Donec et lectus sed turpis interdum sollicitudin. Proin varius lacus lectus, a volutpat lacus ultricies at. Nunc suscipit a orci auctor blandit. Vestibulum at massa erat. Sed dictum, magna a aliquet placerat, turpis nunc molestie nisi, sagittis auctor leo nibh egestas massa. Donec tincidunt sagittis metus id fermentum. Duis in lectus nec dolor rutrum imperdiet ac eget felis. Phasellus justo tortor, eleifend ac libero eget, blandit ultricies ligula. Sed a elementum metus. Vestibulum ex diam, congue sit amet consectetur quis, gravida ut dui. Ut mattis elit et lorem dictum bibendum. Integer ullamcorper est ornare sem lobortis placerat a vitae leo. Mauris a enim at arcu porta sollicitudin. Suspendisse mattis ullamcorper facilisis.

Nullam viverra urna massa, in mollis nulla auctor non. Morbi et venenatis risus. Vivamus elit purus, maximus sit amet ipsum ut, posuere mollis nibh. Donec volutpat diam in imperdiet congue. Maecenas accumsan dictum dictum. Vivamus at erat eget massa porta tempor ut ut nisl. Donec tempor turpis vitae elit fermentum, lacinia lobortis diam volutpat. Integer ac aliquam sapien, id hendrerit dui. Nam ante justo, rhoncus ut laoreet nec, facilisis ac velit.

Quisque eu urna ac augue placerat dictum eget at libero. Ut luctus sapien vel ex tincidunt posuere. Vivamus quis diam at eros molestie dignissim ac at purus. Cras viverra et purus in sollicitudin. Nullam arcu erat, gravida quis facilisis non, condimentum eget orci. Donec rutrum finibus pulvinar. Ut tempor ullamcorper cursus. Ut ullamcorper interdum suscipit. Nulla risus lorem, placerat eu gravida sit amet, fringilla mollis diam. Mauris sit amet diam ut leo venenatis venenatis. Donec interdum ligula nunc, ac elementum dolor efficitur sit amet. Cras turpis purus, luctus vitae hendrerit a, tempus ac velit. Sed et sagittis tortor, quis condimentum velit. Curabitur fermentum ultrices sem, vel vulputate est ornare ac.

Praesent mollis sagittis erat, et consequat nunc. Nunc consequat massa et erat rhoncus laoreet. Vivamus sit amet eleifend orci. Cras convallis placerat neque, id commodo augue vulputate a. Curabitur magna mi, varius blandit congue vel, interdum vel sapien. Vestibulum malesuada purus ut nisl finibus, maximus varius sem pellentesque. In tempor ut eros non dignissim. Mauris ligula nibh, dignissim non dui ut, vestibulum consequat tellus. Cras a nibh et nulla accumsan porttitor sed id odio. Curabitur porttitor a sem nec pellentesque. Aliquam ac augue in nunc faucibus eleifend vel non magna. Phasellus vestibulum dolor pretium magna auctor porta. Proin tincidunt venenatis nibh, vel laoreet ipsum fringilla eget. Cras eu orci a magna porta molestie in ut felis. Vivamus id semper velit, non dignissim lectus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.

Praesent aliquam et dolor ut iaculis. Nullam vehicula elit at nunc auctor vestibulum. Pellentesque iaculis luctus tortor, et molestie ante convallis vel. Sed ipsum magna, lacinia in augue ac, malesuada bibendum ipsum. Integer condimentum porta efficitur. Donec dictum massa ac tincidunt posuere. Ut egestas urna turpis, a vestibulum odio tempus nec. Quisque mattis purus sit amet malesuada tempus. Curabitur aliquam ullamcorper tortor vel dictum.

Proin ornare ipsum vel ex cursus posuere. Curabitur congue, dui eu condimentum luctus, ipsum turpis tincidunt urna, et lobortis ex tellus fermentum lorem. Praesent vehicula, magna eget semper mattis, metus libero aliquet nibh, nec fermentum nulla ex et lectus. Sed quam urna, sagittis eu sem id, egestas commodo ipsum. Ut urna odio, finibus eget lectus ac, aliquet venenatis magna. In semper imperdiet ipsum eget pellentesque. Nullam dapibus consequat mi vitae elementum. Phasellus interdum vestibulum tellus, lacinia posuere ligula dapibus ut. Quisque at leo in augue bibendum vulputate vel vitae mauris.

Etiam massa enim, aliquam vitae dolor a, gravida fringilla dui. Quisque id varius quam. Curabitur maximus pulvinar dui id fermentum. Donec bibendum purus sed viverra molestie. Vivamus lobortis ex orci, sed varius tellus tempus id. Curabitur mollis accumsan condimentum. Cras sollicitudin pharetra ante. In interdum dapibus nunc ac faucibus. Nunc lorem odio, rutrum vel lorem non, molestie rutrum leo. Vestibulum nisi odio, posuere sed nibh vitae, sollicitudin condimentum sem. Aenean at sapien sit amet purus fringilla lacinia. Praesent odio nisi, pharetra non consequat et, dapibus eget nisl.

Proin ut dictum nisi, vitae consectetur dui. Aenean et convallis dolor. Nunc vel urna a lorem iaculis luctus. Fusce sem nibh, placerat at iaculis et, ornare et velit. Nullam nec nisi ac metus tempor pretium ac non purus. Proin imperdiet erat sit amet urna suscipit, eget vulputate urna pretium. Proin vitae tellus imperdiet, dictum ligula et, fermentum purus.

Fusce tempus nibh nec nisi finibus viverra. Duis faucibus lacus ac convallis auctor. Praesent at est auctor, sagittis elit non, ultricies mauris. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam sit amet leo vitae purus tristique consectetur vitae sed nisi. Vivamus pretium aliquam urna, eget pulvinar lectus rhoncus ut. Integer et justo iaculis, faucibus ligula a, egestas lectus. Integer ut enim id sapien fringilla egestas nec eget nisi. Vivamus non eros nec erat tincidunt finibus vel ut turpis.

Etiam augue odio, vulputate a posuere quis, aliquet vel velit. Nullam quis tortor erat. In semper efficitur molestie. Sed dictum vitae erat lobortis hendrerit. Duis dui dolor, iaculis at eros et, posuere bibendum ipsum. Nulla eros purus, sagittis ac gravida et, porttitor in arcu. Aliquam vel facilisis turpis. Pellentesque sit amet interdum massa. Cras ac iaculis mi, et varius eros. Quisque vel massa ipsum. Duis ultricies vel neque quis posuere.

Donec quis vehicula tellus. Pellentesque ullamcorper sollicitudin nulla ac pharetra. Aliquam varius, felis quis varius pretium, enim dui dapibus enim, ac pharetra diam ipsum sed ligula. Vestibulum at nulla vehicula, ullamcorper erat nec, viverra sapien. Sed lorem quam, commodo at mauris eget, varius blandit ex. Aliquam elementum nunc eget lectus cursus, eget ullamcorper risus dictum. Quisque rhoncus varius lectus vitae scelerisque.

Integer bibendum nunc vel sodales convallis. Vestibulum sagittis at augue in malesuada. Donec luctus, justo ut posuere mattis, justo quam fringilla dolor, non rutrum augue nulla vitae arcu. Fusce hendrerit pharetra mi eleifend mattis. Mauris in vehicula nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras luctus volutpat nulla, et porta odio faucibus nec. Etiam fringilla venenatis massa vitae posuere. Quisque quis nibh sed risus porta ultrices. Proin sodales neque in magna semper finibus. Integer at pretium sem. Maecenas nec tortor risus. Etiam bibendum commodo quam vel tempor.

Praesent nec molestie leo. Mauris aliquam metus ac convallis tincidunt. In et turpis et dui condimentum sollicitudin. Praesent felis tellus, cursus ac posuere vel, luctus et tortor. In sit amet convallis justo, sit amet porta dolor. Morbi blandit vehicula sem nec faucibus. Pellentesque tincidunt a dolor sed consequat. Nullam auctor fringilla nibh, eget rutrum leo auctor eu. Aenean elit massa, mattis vitae dolor id, fermentum finibus lectus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc sit amet orci neque. Vivamus finibus non mi id scelerisque. Proin tempus felis scelerisque mi faucibus ullamcorper. Aliquam tincidunt nulla neque, quis laoreet lacus porta nec.

Praesent sed quam risus. Vivamus dictum nec tortor nec mollis. Donec eu aliquet sapien, quis convallis arcu. Fusce at tincidunt mauris, semper tempor lectus. Sed volutpat, quam sed commodo auctor, metus quam dignissim nisi, nec dapibus ex nibh vitae tortor. Cras eleifend vitae massa eget tempor. Sed iaculis dui et maximus iaculis. Quisque dui purus, iaculis quis cursus in, elementum sit amet lorem. Phasellus vitae nulla eu lectus porttitor fringilla.

%\input{introduction}

%\input{methods}

%\input{relatedwork}

%\input{discussion}

%\input{conclusion}




% if have a single appendix:
%\appendix[Proof of the Zonklar Equations]
% or
%\appendix  % for no appendix heading
% do not use \section anymore after \appendix, only \section*
% is possibly needed

% use appendices with more than one appendix
% then use \section to start each appendix
% you must declare a \section before using any
% \subsection or using \label (\appendices by itself
% starts a section numbered zero.)
%


%\appendices
%\section{Proof of the First Zonklar Equation}
%Appendix one text goes here.

% you can choose not to have a title for an appendix
% if you want by leaving the argument blank
%\section{}
%Appendix two text goes here.


% use section* for acknowledgment
\section*{Acknowledgments}
Thanks to stack exchange for solving this.  :(


% Can use something like this to put references on a page
% by themselves when using endfloat and the captionsoff option.
\ifCLASSOPTIONcaptionsoff
  \newpage
\fi


% trigger a \newpage just before the given reference
% number - used to balance the columns on the last page
% adjust value as needed - may need to be readjusted if
% the document is modified later
%\IEEEtriggeratref{8}
% The "triggered" command can be changed if desired:
%\IEEEtriggercmd{\enlargethispage{-5in}}

% references section

% can use a bibliography generated by BibTeX as a .bbl file
% BibTeX documentation can be easily obtained at:
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/doc/
% The IEEEtran BibTeX style support page is at:
% http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/bibtex/
%\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
% argument is your BibTeX string definitions and bibliography database(s)
%\bibliography{IEEEabrv,../bib/paper}
%
% <OR> manually copy in the resultant .bbl file
% set second argument of \begin to the number of references
% (used to reserve space for the reference number labels box)
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{references}


% biography section
% 
% If you have an EPS/PDF photo (graphicx package needed) extra braces are
% needed around the contents of the optional argument to biography to prevent
% the LaTeX parser from getting confused when it sees the complicated
% \includegraphics command within an optional argument. (You could create
% your own custom macro containing the \includegraphics command to make things
% simpler here.)
%\begin{IEEEbiography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{mshell}}]{Michael Shell}
% or if you just want to reserve a space for a photo:

\begin{IEEEbiography}{Natalia Bilenko}
Natalia is a cool grad student with purple hair that studies brains.  She works in the Gallant lab in the Neuroscience department.
\end{IEEEbiography}

\begin{IEEEbiography}{Valkyrie Savage}
Valkyrie is a grad student whose desk is covered in 3D printed stuff.  She works for Bjoern Hartmann in the Berkeley Institute of Design.
\end{IEEEbiography}


% insert where needed to balance the two columns on the last page with
% biographies
%\newpage

% You can push biographies down or up by placing
% a \vfill before or after them. The appropriate
% use of \vfill depends on what kind of text is
% on the last page and whether or not the columns
% are being equalized.

%\vfill

% Can be used to pull up biographies so that the bottom of the last one
% is flush with the other column.
%\enlargethispage{-5in}



% that's all folks
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems to be a feature/bug in `stfloats` removing that package makes the problem go away

Comment: Hmm... actually, removing that package pushes the problematic figure to the very end of the paper (after the author bios)?

Comment: `[b]` is more or less a request to take the float to the end of the document (as it prevents `p`) if you use `\begin{figure}[!bp]` then it comes on the first page (at least the box I get for not having the image comes on the first page) first page

Comment: wow, I got too excited about copy/pasting code trying to figure out how to fix this, and I didn't even realize that [b] was there.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be an interaction between `stfloats` and the class or other packages used. removing that and changing `[b]` to `[!bp]` to allow more flexibility in the float positioning produces a better result:

[image]